# what key123 contains or meaning in the javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript. I was going through some sample code I found:

```
key123: function(arg) {
 ........
 ........
 return <something>
}
```

What is the meaning of this? I could not understand. Thanks.

Comment: An object with a function name key123 which will return some value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a property (key123) has a function for its value. You would be able to call this via `Object.key123(arg)` where `Object` is whatever `key123` is a part of.

Comment: Literally, it is a property that points to a function to provide a value as tymeJV said.  Practically, this is how you define a method for an Object.